# How to make python create N strings without defining all of them manually?

Tags: python

Now I want to run multiple test cases one by one and display the output together line by line.

```
n=input()
for i in range (0,int(n)):
   #takes input and runs the code
   #stores output in a string
#prints output for all n cases one by one
```

How can I make the program to store N outputs of N different test cases in N different strings without actually defining N strings myself??

Comment: You might want to consider creating a reproducible example. For inspiration (even though you do not ask about pandas): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples/38466059

Alternatively, draw an inspiration from the world of R programming language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in a list. As an example:

```
n=input()
testResults = []
for i in range (0,int(n)):
  inp = input()
  output = runCase(inp)
  testResults.append(str(output))
for result in testResults:
   print(results)
```

Str converts output to string and append adds it to the end of the list.

Comment: "How to ask" is a good read for everyone and the question could be improved (I did it) but in general it's a good, sufficiently clear question, otherwise you couldn't have devised the correct answer, could you?